# German text-to-speech on iPhone (Flite/Festival voices? other options?)

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, festival

I'm looking to use English, German, French, Spanish and Italian text-to-speech in an iPhone application. It looks like Flite is basically the only option.

http://festlang.berlios.de/docu/doku.php?id=languages lists all the voices I need, however all links to German ones are dead.

1. Does anyone have another link to German voices for Festival, or maybe have downloaded them before the pages went down and can share?
2. Or maybe you can suggest another free alternative?
3. Another reasonably-priced commercial alternative?
4. Are there any cloud TTS services you can recommend besides unofficial Google Translate-based TTS?

Comment: Hi, did you find maybe that languages? I also need German and Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

Andrey, the link you provided will give you valid data if you use the web.archive.org's 'way back machine'. A mostly whole internet archive. To retreive a Catalan set (TALP/UPC: 10 clunits + 10 hts voices, from prof. speakers): http://web.archive.org/web/20100620222516/http://www.talp.cat/festcat/download.php

Hope this helps,
mca

Answer (score 0):

We've never found a Flite voice, but now there's a [free iSpeech SDK](http://www.ispeech.org/). Not sure about their future plans on the business side (freemium? free beta then paid?), but we may end up integrating it.

Note that there is another problem with Flite: you won't be able to use most Festival voices with it without lots of manual code rewriting. Festival is basically a LISP system, and Festival voices are half-data, half-executable code. Festival-to-Flite conversion tools will choke on the executable code of most voices, so don't get your hopes high.